# xmpp - how i get notification when my friend logged in, he is in my roster list - delphi

Tags: delphi, xmpp, delphi-2010

after one  day of searching and reading rfc's i haven't found any tip in this subject.

i wrote delphi component to access openFire server and all steps until now is good, but i face one problem is:

i have many friends in my roster list ,as example my Account Is **"A@localhost"**  when account **"B@localhost"** logged in I haven't get any notification according to this.

the "B" account is added in my roster list .

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1st of all check some standard jabber-client like Psi or Vaccum or Jajc - do they get those notifications ? If they do - then probably you do something wrong. Compare the stanzas they send and your client send, probably u miss something. Same for receive stream - maybe you receive those stanzas jsut your client fails to recognize them. Try different XMPP server whether it would change the flow. I remember long time ago there was OpenSource Delphi jabber client, but i do not remember the name and if it is still active, but maybe you can get useful insites in its code.

Comment: i found Exodus Client on the internet but not working fine and lost many units and components  , and its build in delphi .net i think. 
so i build new one and i am in the final touches . :)

Comment: Correct! Exodus was the name! i did not looked at Exodus for ages, but when i last looked it seemed to me designed as a set of Microsoft COM components, like MS Office or MSIE, but those components were implemented in Delphi Win32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP presence is a mutual agreement; your friend must accept your request for presence subscription. Try contacting him elsewhere and asking him to do so.

Comment: you right the problem was the client B not accept request yet,after he accept request i have many notifications about his status changes.