# xmpp how to Get Current Connection jid name

Tags: delphi, xmpp

I have two questions about the XMPP protocol:

1) how can I request **Name** for my current JID (My Connected Account) as registered first time by requesting **IQ command** ?

2) How can I change **nickname** for one of my roster accounts(JIDS) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121.txt

Section 2.1.2.4 describes NAME attribute.

> The 'name' attribute ... determined by the user (not the contact). 
>   Although the value of the 'name' attribute MAY have meaning to a human
>   user, it is opaque to the server.  It is OPTIONAL for a client to
>   include the 'name' attribute when adding or updating a roster item.

That basically means the connection itself does not have NAME.

And if you added yourself in your own roster - then it is no different that getting NAME for any other contact.

---

Section 2.1.5 shows the needed stanza to change some attribute - in your case that would be NAME attribute.

---

If you have any quesito nwith XMPP - most easy would be to take some long-existing lcient like JAJC or Vacuum-IM, open XML Log Console, do your action and read which stanzes been really exchanged.

Comment: thanks , i downloaded Vacuum-IM ,its very good idea to see exchanging stanzas, very very  helpful. thanks a gain.

Comment: Well, i suggested you to read stanzas back at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153289 :-) I wonder why u did not do it back then...